# smooth vertex problems

Tags: vertices

i am modeling a bottle, on the flip top cap i have to add this little straight space this is where you put your finger to open the cap, 
well when i added these loop cuts, appears like if i moved it a little bit but i didn't move it, 
please can you help me, thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to slide your vertices along their edges with <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> so that you unsharp all these edges:

[image]

Comment: but in this way the finger space edges on the flip cap will be very smooth but i need them to be sharp !

Comment: you only keep the edges close to each other when you need to mark a sharp edge, in other cases select the rest of the vertices and drag then along their edges with GG

Comment: i did it by select the faces those i want to make them as the finger place, then pressed i to insert faces, then these new face dragged them a little bit backward.